# Regex not working with white spaces

Tags: php, regex, algorithm

in PHP I would like to find the longest repeated string in a string

For this string `ggaaabbbbhjglkhjglkhlggaaabbgbbhjglkhjglkhl`

I use regex `(?=((.+)(?:.*?\2)+))` and it works finding `ggaaabb`

but if I introduce white spaces like this `ggaa abbbbhjg lkhjglkhlggaa abbgbb hjglkhjglkhl` in the string it will fail, why ? how can I make it white space proof ?

Comment: so do you want to remove white space in regex?

Comment: Can you share an example string and what you expect the regex to match?

Comment: The regex itself won't find the longest match in a string, you need to get all matches and grab the longest one. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXaGv8/1) with your pruned regex.

Comment: Regex isn't a good choice for this task.